# Binomial distribution,

Tags: probability, statistics

In the mass production of bolts, it's found that $5$% are defective. Bolts are selected at random and put into packets of $10$.

There's three parts of questions, I've solved the first and second, they are just normal binomial question.  But that's the last part I couldn't.

$2$ packets are selected at random. Find the probability that there are no defective bolts in both the packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting two packets is the same as selecting 20 bolts. That makes this into a regular binomial problem, with 
$$
p = \binom{20}{20}\cdot 0.05^0\cdot0.95^{20}
$$
or even just the product rule directly, with no binomial coefficients: $p = 0.95^{20}$.

Alternatively, if one of the earlier questions asked about the probability that a randomly chosen packet had no defective bolts, say the answer to that was $p_1$, then you can use that as your binomial sample:
$$
p = \binom22p_1^2\cdot (1-p_1)^0 = p_1^2
$$